# How to copy user's profile from one terminal desktop to another?

Tags: desktop-computer, user-profiles, terminal-services

we are using two terminal desktop servers of same versions at work. there is server A and B. Users tend to have only one fully customized user profile only at A or B. We want them to connect to load balancer and automatically assign the user to A or B - so they wouldn't connect directtly to IP address but the "DNS name".

Thus, is there a way to transfer user's profile with Firefox profile, internet explorer profile with all bookmarks, icons stuff etc?

Comment: Are these on the same network / domain?

Comment: yes they are on the same domain and network

Answer (score 3):

You can use Windows NT Backup.

Or using `moveuser.exe` which supports moving between domains (see: [man](http://ss64.com/nt/moveuser.html))

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to run into an issue with the most current files in a user directory issue unless they are synced. You could have a script use one of the tools mentioned copy the profile over at login, or at the beginning of the workday, but then  if the user logs in at a different time during the day and is redirected from A to B and they were in A the documents are not updated. Then you would have to look at syncing files on login and logout this gets tedious and possibly bandwidth intensive.

DFS replication **may** be your solution but it is not without its caveats as seen in this [Technet support blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/09/01/microsoft-s-support-statement-around-replicated-user-profile-data.aspx). Now there are many people who don't have any issues using it in this way, but I don't doubt that it could end turning into a mess.

[Is DFS suited for User profiles?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773238(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_054) Technet article

DFS-FRS PRO Articles/posts [OLD](http://redmondmag.com/articles/2004/06/01/dfs-vs-frs.aspx) - [NEW](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/dfs-real-time-replication-in-roaming-profiles-and-home-directories/)

[DFS-FRS against](http://www.sepago.de/helge/2009/07/30/replicating-user-profiles-between-sites-with-or-without-dfs-why-it-should-be-avoided/)